# deploymaster.yml s3 sync where are secrets saved at?

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, environment-variables

I work on this Website where .github contains deploy-master.yml and looke like the following:
...

```
name: Upload Website

on:
  push:
    branches:
    - master

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@master
    - uses: jakejarvis/s3-sync-action@master
      with:
        args: --acl public-read --follow-symlinks --delete
      env:
        AWS_S3_BUCKET: ${{ secrets.AWS_S3_BUCKET }}
        AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
        AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
        AWS_REGION: 'us-west-1'   # optional: defaults to us-east-1
        SOURCE_DIR: 'public'      # optional: defaults to entire repository
```

...

Any idea where secrets are stored at? Are they on the AWS Servers? I know its env files and they are not visible, but the hoster of the website told me he does not think they are stored on AWS.

They use this : https://github.com/marketplace/actions/s3-sync

Answer (score 0):

The [secrets](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets) are stored either in your github repo settings  (`[repo name] > Settings > Secrets`) or your github organization settings.

You are looking at a [github actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions) file.  As the opening lines of the file say, github actions executes the jobs in the file each time you push to the `master` branch.  Someone in your organization defined the AWS credentials and bucket name as secrets in github in order to run the sync job in the action.